# How to stop a freertos timer and start it again without resetting the current tick count to 0

Tags: timer, freertos

I'm creating a one shot xTimer in freertos. After some time I would like to stop it and then start it again but without resetting the tick count. 
So for example, the period is 10s, after 5s I stop the timer and if I start the timer again I would like the callback to be called after 5s.
At the moment the timer just resets when I start it again and I get the callback after 10s.

Am I missing something?

Comment: you can store the remaining time in the timer, stop it & then reload it again with the stored value whenever you nee..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you reset the timer without changing its period; the timer will run for the period initialized in `xTimerCreate()`. You should first get the time left for this timer, **and stop it only afterwards**. Then you can do anything you need, and later call `xTimerChangePeriod()` with the time left.

```
TickType_t timeLeft;

timeLeft = xTimerGetExpiryTime(myTimer) - xTaskGetTickCount();
xTimerStop(myTimer);

// Do some work

xTimerChangePeriod((myTimer, timeLeft, 1000);
```